# Create multilevel dataframe from given dataframe

Tags: pandas

Given two different df's:

'A'

```
            a  b         
2016-11-21  2  1
2016-11-22  3  4
2016-11-23  5  2 
2016-11-24  6  3 
2016-11-25  6  3
```

'B'

```
            a  b         
2016-11-21  3  0
2016-11-22  1  0
2016-11-23  1  6 
2016-11-24  1  5 
2016-11-25  0  2
```

How can I create a 'multilevel' dataframe of this shape:

'C'

```
            A     B
            a  a  b  b           
2016-11-21  2  3  1  0
2016-11-22  3  1  4  0
2016-11-23  5  1  2  6
2016-11-24  6  1  3  5
2016-11-25  6  0  3  2
```

*index is a 'datatime' object

Thanks

Comment: Is first level correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([A, B], keys=('A','B'), axis=1)
print (df)
            A     B   
            a  b  a  b
2016-11-21  2  1  3  0
2016-11-22  3  4  1  0
2016-11-23  5  2  1  6
2016-11-24  6  3  1  5
2016-11-25  6  3  0  2
```

And for sorting levels add[`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) :

```
df = pd.concat([A, B], keys=('A','B'), axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
print (df)
            A  B  A  B
            a  a  b  b
2016-11-21  2  3  1  0
2016-11-22  3  1  4  0
2016-11-23  5  1  2  6
2016-11-24  6  1  3  5
2016-11-25  6  0  3  2
```

It is not recommended, but possible:

```
df = pd.concat([A, B], keys=('A','B'), axis=1)

cols = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = [cols, df.columns.get_level_values(1)]
print (df)
            A     B   
            a  a  b  b
2016-11-21  2  3  1  0
2016-11-22  3  1  4  0
2016-11-23  5  1  2  6
2016-11-24  6  1  3  5
2016-11-25  6  0  3  2
```

because then is problem select column, because duplicated column names:

```
print (df['A'])
            a  a
2016-11-21  2  3
2016-11-22  3  1
2016-11-23  5  1
2016-11-24  6  1
2016-11-25  6  0
```

Comment: I need the `A` and `B` only as a main header (column)  and under `A` there should be `a a` and under `B` it shoud be `b b`

Comment: @nirajpandey - It is not good idea, because get duplicated MultiIndex, what is reason for it?

Comment: @nirajpandey - added solution with explanation, why is not good idea.